# I need authentication with facebook on WindowsPhone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

i have made many apps, different ways but neither one works.

when i run the app facebook throws me an error that says:
"La configuracion de la aplicacion no permite la URL proporcionada.:Una o varias de las URL proporcionadas no estan permitidas por la configuracion de la aplicacion. Deben coincidir con la URL del sitio web o la URL de la pagina principal de la aplicacion, o el dominio debe ser un subdominio de uno de los dominos de la palicacion."

[google translation]
"The configuration of the application does not allow the URL provided. One or more of the URL you provided do not are allowed by the configuration of the application must match the URL of the website or the URL of the main page of the application, or. the domain should be a subdomain of one of the dominos of palicación.

What do i need to do?

Comment: Are you using WebAuthenticationBroker APIs...??

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Integration in Windows Phone is very simple. Most of the errors that you encounter is due to the fact that the App has not been properly set up on Facebook itself.

Check out this [blog](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/integrating-facebook-in-your-windows-phone-app-using-the-facebook-app/) for step-by-step procedure. It works out fine as I have personally tested it.

You can also check out this [Windows blog post](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/11/14/sign-into-windows-phone-8-apps-with-facebook-login/).